# aDataSort error of undefined or null reference for diffrent columnlist

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have integrated datatable for the result set for the fixed columnlist and it's working fine. The issue am facing currently is, based on the selection of the dropdownlist, I want to load different columnlist with the search result. But when I'm trying to do, it will give error of aDataSort error of undefined or null reference if the columnlist / result set are empty.

So is there any solution to disable "DataSort" property from the datatable property? I ahve tried by assigning,  "aaSorting":"null" /  "aaSorting":"undefined" /  "aaSorting":"[[]]" but it doesn't work out for me.

Appreciated for your help.

Comment: Can you post the code where and how you actually are doing this, or perhaps setup a fiddle?

Comment: [related (newer) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348028/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined)

Answer (score -1):

I have just added bellow code before `DataTable` data binding in ajax success function..

Code:

```
var table = $('#insideGrid').DataTable();
 table.destroy();
```