# Datatable on table getting ajax content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I'd like to use DataTable on a table that gets its content by ajax request.

Basically, I have a php file responding the table content (with `thead`, `tbody` and `tfoot` elements) after an ajax request with jQuery.

main.js like:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'table.php', 
    data: 'dateStart='+$("#dateStart").val(), 
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(response){
        $("table#myTable").html(response);
    }
});

$("table#myTable").DataTable();
```

table.php like:

```
some code ...
echo $reponse;
```

With `jQuery` and `DataTable.js` and `DataTable.css` dependencies as specified on http://datatables.net

But it doesn't work... I'm working on Chrome and the console displays:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

Comment: You have some mistakes in your code. That might be the reason why it doesn't work. Check out ajax `type` and `url` parameter

Comment: By the way in my code there are not such mistakes. But thank you I've edited them. I wrote that topic too fastly :/

Comment: Ok, one more question. Can you confirm that your file `table.php` is called by ajax? Perhaps the url should be `'/table.php'`? And what is `aDataSort`? Is it your variable?

Comment: I don't know what is aDataSort but I can say that it's not my variable. I confirm that my file table.php is called by ajax and this call works as I get the table content.

Comment: Have you tried to disable SORTING ..?
Like this ->  ( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348028/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348028/uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-adatasort-of-undefined)

Comment: Aman Deep it allow to remove this error but the pagination and the searchbar don't work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must call datatable after ajax call end:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'GET', 
    url: 'table.php', 
    data: 'dateStart='+$("#dateStart").val(), 
    dataType: 'html', 
    success: function(response){
        $("table#myTable").html(response);
        $("table#myTable").DataTable();

    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you a lot ! It works. When I think about it I find your solution very logic. Indeed, my table is empty initially. The Ajax request allows to give it some data. But If I call DataTable before it will not works as the table is empty.